# How to understand reboot line in last command?

Tags: centos

How to understand the reboot line in last?

What does the 22:36 mean in that line? In other lines I know that column means when did the people logout, but what does it mean here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the same thing for reboot too. Reboot is a pseudouser. From `man last`

> The pseudo user reboot logs in each time the system is rebooted.  Thus last reboot will show a log of all the reboots since the log file was created